# Set rownumbers to false dynamically in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I like to show row numbers in my grid using the `rownumbers` property.  But if only one row is returned, is there a way to set `rownumbers` to false dynamically.  Why? Seeing a "1" in a column without a header is a little confusing at first glance.  But if there are multiple rows then you quickly realize the purpose of that column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to hide the `'rn'` columns, which hold the record numbers, if the number of records not large enough. Something like

```js
loadComplete: function () {
    if ($(this).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'records') <= 1) { // this.p.records
        $(this).jqGrid('hideCol', 'rn');
    } else {
        // show previous hidden column
        $(this).jqGrid('showCol', 'rn');
    }
}
```