# How to show row numbers greater than 9999 in free jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Code from answer [Set rownumbers to false dynamically in jqgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9740531/set-rownumbers-to-false-dynamically-in-jqgrid)

is used to create button which toggles row numbers.

```
    $grid.jqGrid("navButtonAdd", "#grid_toppager", {
        buttonicon: "fa-list-ol",
        iconsOverText: true,
        caption: '',
        id: "RowNumbers",
        onClickButton: function (options, e) {
            var $me = $(e.currentTarget);
            if ($grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'rownumbers') && $grid[0].p.colModel[0].hidden ) {
                $grid.jqGrid('showCol', 'rn');
                $me.addClass("ui-state-active");
            } else {
                $grid.jqGrid('hideCol', 'rn');
                $me.removeClass("ui-state-active");
            }
            resizeGrid();
            saveWindowState();
        }
    });

    if (isColState && myColumnsState.rownumbers) {
        $("#RowNumbers").click();
    }
```

If row number is greater than 9999 , last digit is not visible.

row numbers 10000 .. 10009 appear as 1000, 10010 appears as 1001 etc.
How to show full row numbers ?
I tried different zoom levels in browser to full row numbers will not appear.
Thied to resize but it looks like row number column is not resizable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jqGrid have `rownumWidth` option which allows to increase the width of `rn` column *during creating of the grid*. If you need to set the width of the column *dynamically* you can use `setColWidth` described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20030652/315935) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29063408/315935). [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ChangeColumnWidthColumnGrouping.htm) shows that you can set the width of `rn` column dynamically. The method `setColWidth` is a part of [free jqGrid 4.8](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), so you can use it directly.